# Debug Node.js with TypeScript and Docker in VS Code: “Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found”

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a dockerized Node.js application written in TypeScript.

I followed a [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Docker-TypeScript) that says that I should configure Nodemon and expose a port on the app container so the debugger can listen to.

When I run the debugger from VS Code I got a disabled Breakpoint with this message “Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found”.

This is my `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Server",
      "type": "node",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "protocol": "auto",
      "request": "attach",
      "remoteRoot": "/server/dist",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/back/dist",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**/*.js"],
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"],
    }
  ]
}
```